# use filter function using http request in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using typeahead of UI-bootstrap for search filter, now I am using data from controller but I want data from JSON using $http. But I am not able to take data from $http request in filter function.

current code

```
// Search Control
vm.searchCtrl = "";
var searchitems = [{
      "name": "Adventure",
      "category": "Activities"
    }, {
      "name": "Cycling",
      "category": "Activities"
    }, {
      "name": "Local guided tours",
      "category": "Activities"
    }, {
      "name": "Delux room",
      "category": "Accommodations"
    }, {
      "name": "Super Delux room",
      "category": "Accommodations"
    }, {
      "name": "Goa",
      "category": "Destinations"
    }, {
      "name": "Bengaluru",
      "category": "Destinations"
    }];

    vm.getSearchitems = function (search) {
        var filtered = filterFilter(searchitems, search);
        var results = _(filtered).groupBy('category').map(function (g) {
            g[0].firstInCategory = true;
            return g;
        }).flatten().value();

        return results;
    }
```

But Now I want like this

```
$http.get('../assets/data/search.json').then(function (response) {
    return vm.searchitems = response;
});
vm.getSearchitems = function (search) {
    var filtered = filterFilter(searchitems, search);
    var results = _(filtered).groupBy('category').map(function (g) {
        g[0].firstInCategory = true;
        return g;
    }).flatten().value();

    return results;
}
```

But "searchitems" are not getting.

Comment: As this is async call, this may no return data at the time of execution of function. Either inject in controller or save in cache/service object during website first hit.

Comment: These asynchronous issues come up all the time in Angular. See my answer below that shows how to invoke the function only after the $http returns the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to invoke your function only after you have the data from $http. So move your call to getSearchItems so it gets called from the $http.

```
$http.get('../assets/data/search.json').then(function (response) {
    return vm.getSearchitems(response);
});
vm.getSearchitems = function (search) {
  var filtered = filterFilter(searchitems, search);
  var results = _(filtered).groupBy('category').map(function (g) {
    g[0].firstInCategory = true;
    return g;
  }).flatten().value();
  return results;
}
```